# Unknown Shape definition [CIRCLE]

Tags: solr

I'm trying to create a new document unfortunately I'm facing this kind of exception:

> Unable to parse shape given formats "lat,lon", "x y" or as WKT because
> java.text.ParseException: Unknown Shape definition [CIRCLE (2.175888
> 41.388587, 20)]

This is my request :

```
/update
{

  "id": 4,
  "document_type_id": 4,
  "geo": "CIRCLE (2.175888 41.388587, 20)"

}
```

This is my filetype:

```
  <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" maxDistErr="0.001" spatialContextFactory="org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory" validationRule="repairBuffer0" distErrPct="0.025" distanceUnits="kilometers"  autoIndex="true" geo="true"/>
```

This is my `geo` field:

```
<field name="geo" type="location_rpt" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIRCLE shape is no more supported with Sorl. We should use instead `SHAPE(POINT(lon lat), DISTANCE in °degree)`.